# c++ Is a class derived from a specific class?

Tags: c++, derived

Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve. This is the problem:

```
class Content{};

class Content1 : public Content{};
class Content1_1 : public Content1{};
class Content1_2 : public Content1{};

class Content2 : public Content{};
class Content2_1 : public Content2{};
class Content2_2 : public Content2{};

class Container{
public:
    Content* c;
};
```

Is it possible to determine if the pointer of the `Container` class points to an object of `Content1` or an object of a class derived from `Content1`?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

If I look up the type of the pointer in the `container` class, it is treated as a `content` type, though it might actually be a `content1` or `content2` type, so dynamic_cast doesn't work.

```
class content{};
class content1 : public content{};
class content2 : public content{};

class container{
public:
    content* c;
};

int main(void)
{
    container* x = new container;
    x->c = new content2;

    if( dynamic_cast<content1*>((content1*)x->c) == NULL){
        //This doesn't fail, eventhough 'content1' and 'content2' shouldn't be compatible.
        //This means that every class, derived from 'content' will be treated as 'content1' when using dynamic_cast.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting what is problem ? And where is pointer of `Base` class ?

Comment: I don't understand the edit. Could you be expand a bit more?

Comment: How did you look up the type of the pointer in the container class - did you use typeid or did you use dynamic_cast - if you used dynamic_cast - can you paste line of code? typeid obviously won't work.

Comment: @user93353 I inserted an example.

Comment: You should do `if( dynamic_cast<content1*>(x->c) == NULL)`, not `if( dynamic_cast<content1*>((content1*)x->c) == NULL)`

Comment: @AndyProwl: Than I get this error (Visual Studio): error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'content' is not a polymorphic type.

Comment: @JMRC: I covered that in my answer. Your base class must have at least one virtual function, and the common practice is to define a virtual destructor. Just like I show in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your types are polymorphic (i.e. if they have at least one `virtual` function), you can use `dynamic_cast<>`. The result of `dynamic_cast<>` will be a null pointer (i.e. `nullptr` for C++11, `NULL` for C++03) in case the pointed object is not actually an instance of the specified class, or of a derived class thereof:

```
Container cont;
Content1* pContent1 = dynamic_cast<Content1*>(cont.c);
if (pContent1 != nullptr)
{
     // cont.c points to an instance of Content1 
     // or a class derived from Content1
}
```

A common practice is to make the *destructor* of your base class virtual, so that objects of a class derived from your base class can be `delete`d through a base class pointer (if the destructor is not `virtual`, attempting to do so results in undefined behavior):

```
class Content //Abstract.
{
public:
    virtual ~Content() { }
//  ^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: dynamic_cast doesn't work, I've edited the question to clear thing up.

Comment: @JMRC It *does* work, you just have to remove the C-cast in your edit. (without replacement).

Comment: It was indeed the virtual function that was missing, now I can use dynamic_cast. I didn't have this error `(Visual Studio): error C2683` in my real programme when using dynamic_cast, because I did use virtual functions over there. Now I know what the real problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `dynamic_cast` - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

It will give you RTTI - Runtime Type Information.

```
Content1 * p = dynamic_cast<Content1 *>(c);
```

if p is non-NULL, then c points to an object which is Content1 or derived from Content1.
However, your class heirarchy needs to be polymorphic. Since your class `Content` is Abstract (I am assuming you have a pure virtual function in Content), your whole heirarchy automatically is polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to know the exact runtime type of a polymorphic class, you should rethink your design. Usually it is better to either keep objects of different types in different containers  (additionally or, instead of one central container) or add a virtual function to each of the derived classes which performs the action where you would have to discriminate between the types.

There is an entry in the C++ FAQ which might help you: [I have a heterogeneous list of objects, and my code needs to do class-specific things to the objects. Seems like this ought to use dynamic binding but can't figure it out. What should I do?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inversion.html)

Comment: There are some cases that virtual functions would have worked, but unfortunately not here. I've updated the question to make everything clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if `Content*` points to an object of a class derived from `Content2` class just cast it with `dynamic_cast` and see.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class Content{public: virtual ~Content(){}};

class Content1 : public Content{public: virtual ~Content1(){}};
class Content1_1 : public Content1{public: virtual ~Content1_1(){}};
class Content1_2 : public Content1{public: virtual ~Content1_2(){}};

class Content2 : public Content{public: virtual ~Content2(){}};
class Content2_1 : public Content2{public: virtual ~Content2_1(){}};
class Content2_2 : public Content2{public: virtual ~Content2_2(){}};

class Container{
public:
    Content* c;
};

int main()
{
    Content* cnt=new Content2_1;
    if(dynamic_cast<Content2_1*>(cnt))
        cout << "True" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```